# Zooming in the reputation graph weirdness

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph

No biggy, but the X-axis labels don't scale in a sensible way when zoomed in.

[image]

Comment: wonderful faces; is that you?

Comment: http://memebase.com/ragebuilder/

Comment: @mikeTheLiar question is a year old. It looks like Oded just changed the tag to completed indicating it's now fixed.

Comment: @Amicable derp, I didn't even notice the dates. Ignore me.